# How to change Alphabetical navigation to persian?

Tags: jquery

I want to use an Alphabetical navigation (using [jQuery ListNav Plugin](http://ericsteinborn.com/jquery-listnav/)) but in persian.
I have already tried to change the jQuery file but it didn't work correctly.
Does anybody know how can I change it to persian alphebet?

Comment: Possibly useless comment: Be careful about Unicode. Sorting may get unusual.

Comment: You should specify the "correct" (desired) behaviour and the actual one (and probably show some code example).

Comment: The library you refer to doesn't support non-english alphabet

Comment: @Dekel yes its work for non-english alphebet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to modify few lines in the plug-in. Edit jquery-listnav.js (notepad++ for example). First change the encodage of the file to utf-8 without BOM. Then check the line where array letters is defined (around line 20), and change it to persian alphabet :

```
letters = [ '_','آ', 'ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ','س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی', 'ي', '-' ],
```

Then got to the addLetterClass function (around line 200) and change the regex test :

```
if ( /\W/.test(firstChar) )
```

with this one :

```
if ( /\[\u0600-\u06FF]/.test(firstChar) )
```

wich is the range of persian characters